# Fast algorithm required to detect changes in pixels

Tags: image, algorithm, processing, detection, pixel

I am looking for an algorithm to detect changes in a pixel array.  In the picture below, the red line illustrates the pixel array.  I want the algorithm to recognize and trigger once the golf club below passes through the red line.

My original thought was to read the pixels along the line and to detect changes in color (specifically on the lower half of the line) when the color changes above a certain threshold.

Is there a better way to do this or an algorithm I can use which detects once the golf club passes the red line?

Thank you for your thoughts.

[image]

Comment: Implement such a detection on a lower resolution image with reduced colormap is often good enough and faster than to analyze the original image,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracking the pixels along the line is a feasible approach. 
I recommend not to check the pixels in the order top to bottom or bottom to top, I recommend a kind of interlacing order to increase the chance to detect a change with few pixel-checks.

Here is what I mean:

If the index the pixels from the to to the bottom by 0,1,2,3,..63  [just an example]

I would check e.g. this order
0,32 ,16,48 ,8,24,40,56, 4,12,20,28,36,44,52,60, ...

Or if you predict a non equal distributed probability for the change of the pixels, you can take even this in account and find an order of pixel checks with, detects the change with the lowest average pixel checks.

Comment: Nice idea.  I would suggest also checking a few more pixels after finding the first significant difference -- just to make sure that it wasn't random noise.  (If the golf club is really in the red zone then other nearby pixels should also have large differences.)

Comment: MrSmith42 I am liking this idea.  Can you explain some more on the non-equal distributed probability and lowest average pixel checks? Also j_random_hacker makes a good point on random noise.  When outside, I am sure that the red zone will exhibit random noise (e.g. leaves blowing), but this would be low noise, any thoughts on how to distinguish this noise vs. golf club?  Maybe applying the average thru a low-pass filter?  I like the idea of interlacing but how would I apply this process on a frame by frame check?

Comment: You can reduce the noise problem by reducing resolution and color depth. But than you still need to have a limit how many pixels must have changed at least to decide that this is a real change related to the golf club.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of video-source do you use? Most video compressions already use differences between images to reduce the amount of data to store.

It might be a quite a bit of work, but you might be able to see the change directly in the compressed data without decoding it. Sounds like an interesting challenge to me to implement detection of change in a video, by simply reading the undecoded data.

Comment: Actually, I have the raw pixel maps available from iOS hence they are stored as images vs. video